# How to give base url in angular when retrieve image from api

Tags: angular

**How to get api url when retrieve image from database**

```
            <table class="table">
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Image</th>

              </tr>
              <tr *ngFor="let image of images">

                <td>{{image.id}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{image.image}}"/></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this

```
           <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Image</th>

          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let image of images">

            <td>{{image.id}}</td>
            <td><img src="mypath/{{image.image}}"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Thanks.